# Context saving – how to read segment registers in C and instruction pointer?

Tags: c, assembly

Hell'o. I want to create a program which saves register set – process context. When I try to read CS register, my compiler and IDE tell me, that register "CS" doesn't exist.

```
    register int *cs asm ("cs");
```

Am I doing it right? Saving process context means saving every register – especially Code Segment (and other segments as well) – those registers are required to restore process image and start executing where last execution stopped.

Comment: You will need to save it from code using a `mov`, as gcc inline asm (that you are presumably using) doesn't support segment registers in constraints. PS: `cs` is not a pointer.

Comment: Note that segment registers may reference custom descriptor table entries (or base addresses in 64 bit mode) which you also need to save.

Comment: To retrieve the ip, you'll need to use a call instruction to the next instruction which should be a pop instruction.

Comment: Without context it's going to be a mess. Most of the time `cs:ip` is "free" to save because of the way the running task was interrupted. Also, C is probably not the right tool to do it, especially when using local vars.

Comment: No, you're not even on the right track.  GNU C register-asm local variables are not guaranteed to work for reading registers in C, only for guarantee what input an operand picks for `"r"(var)`  constraints (and `"=r"` or `"+r"`) to Extended asm.  There's no constraint that will ever pick a segment register, so you can't have a variable using CS.  Just read it with inline asm.  Or better, don't support changing CS at all.

Comment: It is best to write this kind of code in assembler as there are too many unpredictable factors to make a C implementation workable at all.

Answer (score 0):

> Saving process context means saving every register

Of course you can save `cs` and `eip`. However ...

- ... these two registers contain the location (address) of the instruction currently being executed.

  This means that these registers will always contain the address of the code that saves the context registers.

  Why do you want to store this information when these registers always contain the same value?
- ... what do you think what happens when you restore these registers?

  Because these two registers contain the address of the instruction currently being executed, the only way to "restore" these two registers is to jump to the instruction that saved the values of the register.

  You'll run into an endless loop...

  Is this really what you want to do?

> I want to create a program which saves register set – process context.
>
> ```
> register int *cs asm ("cs");
> ```

Now it's getting very scary:

If you really want to write some code that saves the CPU context (e.g. for manually implementing a `try`-`catch` mechanism in "low-level" C), you should write the complete function in assembler.

Don't try to write this using inline assembly within C functions!

Otherwise you don't know how the "compiled" C code will interact with the assembler code; it's highly probable that your program won't work.